# Why is there an ftplugin directory for each plugin?

Tags: plugin-vimtex, ftplugin

I am trying to get started with VimTeX. I am reading through a guide (https://www.ejmastnak.com/tutorials/vim-latex/vimtex.html) and using vim-plug to manage plugins. I am very new to Vim generally, and so I was wondering what the purpose is of there being ftplugin directories associated with each plugin.

Is it still necessary to create a new ~/.vim/ftplugin/ directory? Should I do anything with the other ftplugin directories that get created once a plugin is installed (i.e., ~/.vim/plugged/vimtex/ftplugin/)?

Sorry if these questions are dumb!

Comment: Do you have an answer to your question? If so maybe could you accept it using the v green button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 1):

### Context

At the beginning there were only one `ftplugin` folder and siblings (e.g. `ftdetect`). All the plugins were sharing these folders.

The consequences were that:

- Plugins installation lead to conflicts (writing the same files in the same folders)
- Uninstalling the plugins were complex

Later some plugin authors introduced a way to install their plugin in their own structure (manipulating `runtimepath`). The idea have been taken by plugin managers like `Vundle`, `Vim-Plug` and became the standard way to deploy plugins.

### Answers

You don't have to create `~/.vim/ftplugin/`.

You shouldn't touch the plugin folder (i.e. the subfolders of `~/.vim/plugged/`) unless you want to uninstall the plugin (delete the corresponding folder).

If you play with plugin I advice you to install a plugin manager like [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug)

Comment: "Vim 8 introduced the possibility for the plugin to have their own structure." --- No, this possibility was always there and was taken advantage of by different people in different ways. I believe tpope was one of the first to popularize the idea of manipulating the `runtimepath` with vim-pathogen. Later came vim-plug and other plugin managers, and even later the new package feature was added to Vim.

Comment: Thanks for your comment I'll adapt my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Just to be clear, is there any reason to add an ftplugin directory manually to ~/.vim/? Also, is there any reason to mess with files like tex.vim in the VimTeX plugin?

Comment: There are no reason to mess with tex.vim unless you want to contribution to the plugin.

Comment: The ftplugin folder may be used to amend filetypes configuration that comes with Vim